# How does TestCafe authenticate to an IAP secured application

Tags: authentication, testing, automated-tests, testcafe, identity-aware-proxy

Can someone guide on how can TestCafe authenticate to an IAP secured service/app please? I've tried to read this guide [here](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/authentication-howto) but it seems a tad complicated for me. If anyone has done this before it will be great if you can share. Thank you in advance.

Comment: TestCafe runs tests on Node.js. So, you can access any secured services in the same way as in a Node.js application.
Please describe your scenario in greater detail. What actions do you need to execute in tests? Do you need to authenticate from a user account or from a service account?

Answer (score 1):

We've implemented it by using [google-auth-library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-auth-library#json-web-tokens) and extending the [`RequestHook`](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/test-api/requesthook/) in Testcafe.

- You need to have the Google IAP credentials (step 1 and 2 in your
  [link](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/authentication-howto)) to get the JWT token.
- Once you got the JWT token, you add it
  as Authorization Header for each request you do to the application
  (achieved by extending [`RequestHook`](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/test-api/requesthook/)).

The code is approximately the following for the helper function:

```
import { RequestHook } from 'testcafe';

import { GoogleAuth } from 'google-auth-library';

export class GoogleIapJWTAuthorization extends RequestHook {

  constructor () {
    // No URL filtering applied to this hook
    // so it will be used for all requests.
    super();

    const auth = new GoogleAuth({
      credentials: serviceGoogleAccount
    });

    console.log('Google Authentication');

    console.log(`Loaded Service Account ${GoogleAccount.client_email}`);
    auth.getClient()
    .then(client => client.fetchIdToken(`${GoogleAccount.targetAudience}`))
    .then(token => {
        console.log(`Successfully authenticated with Identity Aware Proxy. Id Token: ${token}`);
        this._token = token;
        return token;
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(`Identity Aware Proxy Authentication Failed. Id Token: ${token}`);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
        process.exitCode = 1;
    });
}
  getGoogleJwtToken() {
    return this._token;
  }

  onRequest (e) {
    //Authorization header for authentication into Google Auth IAP
    e.requestOptions.headers['Authorization']= `Bearer ${this._token}`;
  }

  onResponse (e) {
      // This method must also be overridden,
      // but you can leave it blank.
  }
}
```